# Jackson ObjectMapper ignores empty String during serialisation

Tags: java, objectmapper

Let's say that I have a object payload like:

```
{
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "number": "01234 567 890",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "number": "",
    }
  ]
}
```

and method which parses it to JSON

```
    public String getJson(Object object) {
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I am setting ObjectMapper in the constructor like:

```
    @Autowired
    public ServiceImpl(@Qualifier("objectMapper") ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        configureObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    }
```

and `objectMapper` configuration in the method looks like this:

```
    private static void configureObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_PATTERN));
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
    }
```

The problem is that Jackson for method call `writeValueAsString` returns

```
{
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "number": "01234567890",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
    }
  ]
}
```

and for some reason skip the empty string in the second object.

When I will reassign ObjectMapper in the method getJson() to use Codehause instance

```
    public String getJson(Object object) {
        org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper objectMapper = new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper()
                .configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);

        String result = null;
        try {
            result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

it does not skip empty strings which is the intended behaviour. I tried different configurations but nothing brought a desirable effect. I will be grateful for suggestions on configuring Jackson and making it accept/serialise `""` as an empty String without ignoring it.
I am using the `Jackson-core` 2.14.0 version.

Comment: Remove objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY)

Comment: Are you deserializing from JSON (with empty string) to object, and then serializing again to JSON? What if you create the object with an empty string in Java and then serialize using your `Include.NON_EMPTY` configuration ? Don't see that as code-example.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this.
ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT

According official doc. [Jackson ObjectMapper](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.14.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html)

```
public class Demo1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{\n" +
                "  \"phoneNumbers\": [\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"id\": 1,\n" +
                "      \"number\": \"01234 567 890\"\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"id\": 2,\n" +
                "      \"number\": \"\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  ]\n" +
                "}";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);

        PhoneNumbersWrapper phoneNumbersWrapper = objectMapper.readValue(json, PhoneNumbersWrapper.class);

        List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = phoneNumbersWrapper.getPhoneNumbers();
        for (PhoneNumber phoneNumber : phoneNumbers) {
            System.out.println("ID: " + phoneNumber.getId());
            System.out.println("Number: " + phoneNumber.getNumber());
        }
} }
```